# Unable to create Composer environment [GCP]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to create basic Composer environment:

- image version: `1.17.8/2.1.4`
- using service account with `composer.worker` permission
- my own user has `project.owner` permission
- public ip

All my attempts failed with following error:

```
Http error status code: 400
Http error message: BAD REQUEST
Errors in: [Web server]; Error messages:
The caller does not have permission
    Required 'deploymentmanager.typeProviders.create' permission for 'projects/<my-project>/global/typeProviders/europe-west2-<name-id>-addons-gke-typer'
```

`deploymentmanager.typeProviders.create` is covered by `Deployment Manager Type Editor`, so I added this permission to both my account and service account, but the error remains the same.
`Cloud Composer Service Agent` account is present in the project without any modifications to its permissions.

Is there anything else I can check or something that I missed during the set up?

Answer (score 1):

For an account (whether User Account or Service Account) to be able to create a Composer Environment, the account must have a `composer.environments.create` permission.

And according to Google Cloud's documentation on Cloud Composer Access Control,

> The **Composer Worker** role provides the permissions necessary to **run a Cloud Composer environment
> VM** and intended for service accounts.

The **Composer Worker** role is not intended for creation of environments thus, it does not have the `composer.environments.create` permission.

If you want your service account to be able to create a Composer environment, you will need to assign the role **Composer Administrator** and this has the `composer.environments.create` permission needed.

You may refer to [Access Control for Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/access-control) for the complete list of permission for **Composer Worker**, **Composer Administrator** and other Composer related roles.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it wasn't the case. It turned out that Composer was unable to create PubSub subscriptions in my GCP project (no idea why - no policies were enabled that would prevent this). I just created new GCP project and Composer setup worked perfectly.